# Get current folder name without an absolute path

Tags: java

How to get the parent name of the current working directory with out the absolute path name, just the name of the folder. For example, if I am on "C:\Users\Test" folder I need only "Test".

Comment: Show us your code. We will help.

Answer (score 0):

**Quick answer:**

```java
String currentDir = Paths.get("").toAbsolutePath().getFileName().toString();
```

**Full explanation:**

You first ask for the current directory:

```java
Paths.get("");
```

But a toString() wouldn't show you anything, as you are where you are.

So then you ask for the absolute path:

```java
Paths.get("").toAbsolutePath();
```

But a toString() would get you the full path `C:\Users\Test`.

So now you ask for the "getFileName", which gets you just the name of the directory, and a toString() to convert it to a string:

```java
String currentDir = Paths.get("").toAbsolutePath().getFileName().toString();
```

Comment: While this code may answer the question, providing additional context regarding *why* and/or *how* this code answers the question improves its long-term value.

Comment: @Sneftel Now edited.  

Answer (score -1):

There is two way to get the name of the current working folder in java

- Using java.lang.System class

  ```
  String directory=System.getProperty("user.dir");
  String currentFolderName=directory.substring(directory.lastIndexOf("\\")+1);
  System.out.println(currentFolderName);
  ```
- Using java.nio.file.Paths class

  ```
  System.out.println(Paths.get(directory).getFileName());
  ```